# MxGraph - How to delete edges with the delete key

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

im trying to remove the edges when the user presses the delete key. I've been reading the docs but couldn't find anything. I can implement a custom function that will remove the edges, but I only want to do it if there is no function or property available in mxgraph

I have these options enabled atm

```
mxEdgeHandler.prototype.snapToTerminals = true;
mxEdgeHandler.prototype.removeEnabled = true;
```

Comment: PS this is the lib: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/ :)

Comment: custom function it is then

Comment: Yes, I wrote a custom function to handle it